# Why is my Evaluate Reverse Polish Notation not working?

Tags: python, algorithm, math

This is my code, and I am failing of this test case:

```
["10","6","9","3","+","-11","*","/","*","17","+","5","+"]
```

I printed out the stack and this is how the stack looks:

```
[10]
[10, 6]
[10, 6, 9]
[10, 6, 9, 3]
[10, 6, 12]
[10, 6, 12, -11]
[10, 6, -132]
[10, -1] <-- ??
[-10]
[-10, 17]
[7]
[7, 5]
[12]
```

When we get to -132, 6, it should return us 0. Not sure why it returns -1 tho, I tried other compiler it works. So my question is, what is going on?

```
def evalRPN(self, tokens):
    setOfOperator = {'+', '*', '/', '-'}
    def evaluate(x1, x2, operand):
        if operand == "+":
            return x1 + x2
        elif operand == '-':
            return x2 - x1  # Reverse order for subtraction
        elif operand == '*':
            return x1 * x2
        elif operand == '/':
            return int(x2 / x1)  # Reverse order for division

    stack = []
    
    for char in tokens:
        if char not in setOfOperator:
            stack.append(int(char))
        else:
            stack.append(evaluate(stack.pop(),  stack.pop() , char))
    if stack:
        return stack[-1]
```

Comment: I assume there should be `*` between `-11` and `/` (guess the Stack Overflow markup has mangled it)

Comment: Are you using Python 2.x, by any chance?  6/-132 evaluates to -1 in that environment, since both sides are integers.

Comment: Have you single-stepped your program in the debugger? And, as mentioned previously, have you written a test program to see what happens when you divide 6/-132?

Answer (score 5):

### Why this happens

This is a Python 2 vs Python 3 difference.

In Python 2, the `/` operator performs integer division, and rounds towards negative infinity. So `6/-132` gives `-1`, and of course `int(6/-132)` also gives `-1`.

In Python 3, the `/` operator performs float division, so `6/-132` is `-0.045`. Then the `int` function truncates decimals, so `int(6/-132)` is `0`.

(Note, the `//` operator in Python 3 does integer division, so `int(6//-132)` is `-1`.)

Your desired result is `0` (as in Python 3) but presumably your code is being run against Python 2.

### Options to fix

#### Upgrade!

Firstly, does your platform have a way that you can run the code on Python 3 instead? Ideally it would, since Python 2 has been officially obsolete since 2020.

#### Float division

If you can't use Python 3, you can force float division, which will behave consistently across Python 2 and Python 3:

```
elif operand == '/':
    return int(float(x2) / x1)
```

A quick illustration:

```
print int(6/-132)
print int(float(6)/-132)
```

prints:

```
-1
0
```

#### Backporting Python 3 division into Python 2

Alternatively, if the platform you are running on allows it, you can make Python 2 implement the Python 3-style `/` with:

```
from __future__ import division
```

Another quick illustration:

```
from __future__ import division
print int(6/-132)
```

prints:

```
0
```

Comment: Almost certainly they can simply choose "Python3" with two clicks. [link](https://leetcode.com/problems/evaluate-reverse-polish-notation/)